# JavaScript: Cursor position in prompt box

Tags: javascript

The default behaviour of a prompt box selects the entire text when opened. Can this behaviour be changed to a custom position of the mouse cursor within the box?

`prompt('Please choose your left window:', document.URL);`

[image]

For example I want the cursor to be pointed directly after the `//`.

Comment: Prompts are generally a bad idea, they belong to the browser and not to you. I suggest using a modal dialog instead - kind of like a prompt but inside the page's DOM and controlled completely with the page's JavaScript. It's a lot less annoying and focus stealing to the user and you can do stuff like you ask here very easily like you normally would with a text input.

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Can you give me an example of such a modal dialog, please?

Comment: just add a div-box to your markup with display-none and on some event .. for example a click, you make it visibile and position it in the middle on top of all other elements, then you can do whatever you want

Comment: If you are open to jQuery you can use jQuery UI Modal Dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaroslavya/KLtCJ/)
Main idea to remove selection is the following:

```
$input.focus();
$input.val($input.val());
```

First focusing the input, then resetting it's value. 
It's DOM based, and will not work for prompt window. Based on authors comment to the question.

Comment: -1 And you are sure, that this really works in prompt-dialogs?

Comment: Note, above orschiro agreed to try DOM based modal dialogs. That`s the example of such dialog. Sorry for not clearing this up, updated. Please, remove -1 if that was the reason.

Comment: +1. This works perfectly. When it comes to popups and prompts it's always the best to make them yourself to make it easier to customize/code. JQuery UI however is not needed unless you want JQuery UI elements specifically (even JQuery itself can be ignored if you're good with Javascript).